# Kafka JDBC source connector - composite key field from different source field types?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm pulling data into a topic from a SQL Server table that has a composite primary key made of the following:

`NAME_COMPANYCODE` and `NAME_POLNUM` fields are `VARCHAR`; `NAME_SEQNO` is `INT`.

I have the following transform applied in order to have a key that matches the composite primary key of the source table (note - this is ksql syntax):

```
"transforms"='createKey',
"transforms.createKey.type"='org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey',
"transforms.createKey.fields"='NAME_COMPANYCODE,NAME_POLNUM,NAME_SEQNO'
```

However, when I print the topic in ksql, I see the following:

```
key: [Struct{NAME_COMPANYCODE=1,NAME_POLNUM=11055628,NAME_@6000291475319763325/-], 
value: {"NAME_COMPANYCODE": "1", "NAME_POLNUM": "11055628", "NAME_SEQNO": 1,...
```

It seems the `NAME_SEQNO` is getting changed to `NAME_@6000291475319763325/-` in the `key` structure. In the `value` section the name appears as expected.
How can I get the field name to be the expected `NAME_SEQNO` in the `key`?

Comment: [sample code](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/valuetokey.html#examples): note that double quotes are being used

Comment: Thanks for the note - I've clarified that I'm using ksql to define the connector. In ksql the syntax requires a double quote on the property and a single quote around the value of the property (which took a beat to figure out). It would appear this print problem is a known issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/5514

Comment: What version of ksqlDB are you using?

Comment: CLI v6.0.0, Server v6.0.0